# unwanted periodical restarts

Tags: cron, restart

A couple of weeks ago, I thought I solved the cron job problem which is responsible for unwanted periodical restarts in 60 mins. I used acpi=off line for this.

But now the problem occurs again with a difference. It restarts in every ~60,5 mins instead of 60 and cannot see the restart comments in /var/log/syslog file like the previous problem.

How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

last lines before (and one after) the restart:

```
Jul 27 01:48:37 cmsmetu-desktop rtkit-daemon[1443]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.    

Jul 27 01:48:37 cmsmetu-desktop kernel: [   22.810656] hda-intel: IRQ timing workaround is activated for card #0. Suggest a bigger bdl_pos_adj.

Jul 27 01:48:37 cmsmetu-desktop rtkit-daemon[1443]: Successfully made thread 1618 of process 1618 (n/a) owned by '104' high priority at nice level -11.

Jul 27 01:48:37 cmsmetu-desktop rtkit-daemon[1443]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.

Jul 27 01:48:37 cmsmetu-desktop pulseaudio[1618]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.

Jul 27 01:49:33 cmsmetu-desktop ntpdate[1349]: step time server 91.189.94.4 offset 52.797886 sec

Jul 27 01:49:42 cmsmetu-desktop NetworkManager[798]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.

Jul 27 01:49:42 cmsmetu-desktop NetworkManager[798]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...

Jul 27 01:49:42 cmsmetu-desktop NetworkManager[798]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...

Jul 27 01:49:42 cmsmetu-desktop NetworkManager[798]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.

# RESTART HERE (text for clarification only, did not actually appear in the file)

Jul 27 02:17:01 cmsmetu-desktop CRON[1637]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Comment: Could you provide more context to your question? With the current description it is not possible to answer it because we lack information. What cron job are you running every hour? Why would it restart the computer if the acpi is ON? Does your computer restart if you deactivate this cron job? etc.

Comment: Normally I have nothing to with cron job. It had been restarting after the installation of ubuntu even though I did not crate the cron job.I solve the problem with the acpi=off comment (in "grub" file). For a week or two it works normally, but the periodic restarts have started again for a week. PS: I am not sure whether it is a cron job or not. It is just what I deduce from internet. Sorry if it doesn't.

Comment: In /var/log/syslog just before the system restart (even if you do not see the restart message, you should see the start sequence), what are the 10 lines preceding the restart?

Comment: i added it right bottom of the post, but cannot pate it in a good shape; sorry.

Comment: Hello @mrq1901 sadly your syslog does not show any restart. Are you sure your system "restarted" during that period or perhaps did you remove the restart messages. In case of restart (even hard one) you should see a similar message on next boot: `Jul 28 15:04:00 laptop-64 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="957" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start` (notice the word "start" at the end of the line). What makes you think your system restarts?

Comment: beacuse, the voice of the fan increases very rapidly, it shuts down itself and then restarts again. after your last question i also suspect whether it is a normal restart or a crush down. by the way thank you very much for your efforts so far.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understood :-(. You hear the fan noise getting first louder, then you do not hear it and finally you hear the fan noise again. Is that what you meant? I quickly setup a test VM with Ubuntu 14.04 and did both a soft and a hard reset (simulating a Ctrl-Alt-Del and simulating basically unplugging the power cord), in both cases I could see an equivalent "start" message in Syslog that I paste above. When doing the hard reset, I did not see any "shutdown" or "reboot" message, but I could see the "start" one. Could you clarify again the "behaviour" you are seeing?

Comment: ok i suppose it was not clear enough.let me try again:beacuse, the voice of the fan increases very rapidly, it (the computer) shuts down itself and then restarts again. after your last question i also suspect whether it is a normal restart or a crush down. by the way thank you very much for your efforts so far

Comment: in addition, the already increased voice of the fan continues about 2-3 seconds and then computer restarts. for these last seconds, syslog is filled with pages of lines before restart.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? I am asking that because I do not understand why the "first" line in Syslog after the restart is about CRON. Are you using an older version where the syslog messages are sent to the file /var/log/messages? If yes, could you also post the last lines before the restart (including a few lines after the restart) for that file too?

Comment: Did you check if in your grub configuration the "acpi=off" is still there? It could have been removed by an update which could have regenerated the grub menu. Make sure it is in `/etc/default/grub` (if you are using Grub2).

Comment: It is Ubuntu 12.04. syslog is in /var/log. Yes "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off" " line is still there.

Comment: I will maybe sound skeptical, but the fact is that until now you haven't provided any proof that your computer does restart/reboot. So in order to clear this up I propose that the next time you think the restart happens, post the complete `/var/log/syslog` and post the output of the command `uptime`. I want to help, but I am confused by the fact that upon start-up we should see a "start message" in syslog/messages. If we do not see it, then it has not restarted (unless you have other troubles such as disk full, etc.). Could you check the permssion on syslog (`ls -l /var/log/syslog`)?

Comment: As an example after a restart of an Ubuntu 12.04 box, I have this visible in `/var/log/syslog`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7970181/

Comment: ok.when i checked ls -l /var/log/syslog. it gives "-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 1147713 Aug  8 09:21 /var/log/syslog". also there is one thing that i am not sure whether it is related or not. just after the restart and before ubuntu downloading screen there is a white line on black screen says [      6.523891] kvm: disabled by bios.

Comment: and here what it says between two restarts: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7986331/ ----there is cron related lines, starting from the line 1118, which made me say it may be a cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK thank you for your latest comments!

I would bet that CRON is here not the culprit. But just in case could you provide the content of `/etc/cron.hourly`?

I would try to remove the option `acpi=off` on boot and see if this happen again.

Is your computer a laptop or not? In case it is not a laptop, does it has a screen attached to it or is it headless? If you have a screen what Video card (GPU) do you have and which video driver are you using?

Finally, you are probably experiencing a kernel crash. Could you enable Kernel crash dump by following the following official Ubuntu guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html
We could then try to see a reason. For this use the link http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/crash-analyze.html. Mainly execute the command `crash` using sudo and type bt once prompted. Put all the output on pastebin (you can remove sensitive information if there are any).

Comment: Hello @mrq1901 did this answer helped you? Did you progress in your investigation?

Comment: hello @Huygens, sorry for late reply. I followed the link related to kernel crash but cannot do it since sudo apt-get install doesn't work. Since it is a server for our study group and urgency of the situation, my colleague deal with it. He cannot apply find a solution also and preferred to format the pc. Sorry for that, it was out of my control. Yet, I try to check the condition asap and report here if the problem still exits. Thanks for your help so far.